# Angular web app having extra ! in the url

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-routing, route-provider

I have a basic Angular webapp running on ec2 ubuntu 16.04, using routing($routeProvider). When I open the application home page say example.com, instead of opening http://example.com/#/ it opens http://example.com/#!/ there is an extra ! which is messing up the whole url/routing structure. Not sure what I am doing wrong, Please advice.

Comment: what version of angular are you using... check the migration guide if using angular 1.6... https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular version 1.6 adds a "!" to $location.. check the angular page below...

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#commit-aa077e8

> **$location:**
>
> **Due to [aa077e8](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/aa077e81129c740041438688dff2e8d20c3d7b52)**, the default hash-prefix used for $location hash-bang
>   URLs has changed from the empty string ('') to the bang ('!'). If your
>   application does not use HTML5 mode or is being run on browsers that
>   do not support HTML5 mode, and you have not specified your own
>   hash-prefix then client side URLs will now contain a ! prefix. For
>   example, rather than mydomain.com/#/a/b/c the URL will become
>   mydomain.com/#!/a/b/c.
>
> If you actually want to have no hash-prefix, then you can restore the
>   previous behavior by adding a configuration block to you application:
>
> ```
> appModule.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
>   $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
> }]);
> ```

Comment: If this resolved your issue please accept this as the answer thanks :)